# How can I display the ID of each image in an Image Collection (Sentinel-2 Level 2A) in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2

I need to work with [Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-2A](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR#image-properties) collection in Google Earth Engine, but I need the ID (according to the naming convention in this format: **MMM_MSIXXX_YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_Nxxyy_ROOO_Txxxxx_**

How can I keep or display the ID of each image in a Sentinel-2 Collection after applying a function to mask clouds, bounds filters and date filters. Because I only get the properties system:time_start and system:index (highlighted in yellow in the image below).

You can find the code in [this link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/e436113bcbae29af7bf8695643fe87c3)
[image: image below]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After applying a function, the image loses the original properties. `maskS2clouds` is doing that, not bounds and date filters as you mentioned.

The function `copyProperties` lets you preserve properties after applying functions.

The code you have preserves one property from the original image in this line (inside `maskS2clouds` function):

```
return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
```

Yo can change that line preserving all properties:

```
return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image);
```

Or preserving only granule ID (with time stamp - recommended for further analysis -):

```
return image
.updateMask(mask)
.divide(10000)
.copyProperties(image,['GRANULE_ID','system:time_start']);
```